# Apache local virtual host is listed but doesn't work

Tags: apache

I need help configuring my website to be accessed in the local server as a virtual directory in Apache.
I am trying to use the port 8050, and when i open localhost:8050 , it shows:

> This site can’t be reached
>   localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

when i try to access my localhost:80 in the browser, it shows the default blank page with the message "It Works"
if i change my virtualhost to *.80 in the config, it keeps showing the default message "It Works", instead of my page.

`apachectl -t` returns Syntax OK
the command:
`apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` returns:

> VirtualHost configuration:
>      *:8050           personal.com (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)

the Servername in my httpd.conf file is localhost, and it also contains:
Listen 8050
and
Listen localhost:8050

this is my httpd-vhosts in etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8050>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/renatobento/Documents/Projetos/Personal"
    ServerName personal.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/personal.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/personal.com-access_log" common
<Directory "/Users/renatobento/Documents/Projetos/Personal">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The path "/Users/renatobento/Documents/Projetos/Personal" seems correct, and contains a simple index.html with some content, which works in the browser with file protocol: "file:///Users/renatobento/Documents/Projetos/personal/index.html"

Already executed
`apachectl stop` , `apachectl start` , and `apachectl restart` thousand times

after the stop command, the localhost:80 still shows the message "It Works"

I am using MAC OSX 10.3 high sierra, apache 2.4

> Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) Server built:   Apr  3 2018
>   23:45:11 Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:76 Server loaded:  APR
>   1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4 Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4 Architecture:   64-bit Server MPM:     prefork   threaded:     no
>       forked:     yes (variable process count) Server compiled with....  -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE  -D APR_HAS_MMAP  -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)  -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE  -D
>   APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE  -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT  -D
>   APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD  -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS  -D
>   DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256  -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"  -D
>   SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"  -D
>   DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"  -D
>   DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"  -D
>   DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"  -D
>   AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"  -D
>   SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

edit:
tried with a different port :9050 but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Check whether **permissions** for DocumentRoot

```
/Users/renatobento/Documents/Projetos/Personal
```

are set to be **accessible** for **everyone**.

> Your overall config seems to be good.

---

Check your **`/etc/hosts`** file, if it contains something like

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    personal.com
```

> To edit this file, type `sudo nano /etc/hosts` in Terminal and after editing, type `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to flush DNS cache.

Comment: just checked in the gui finder> right click in the folder > get info. it was everyone - read only, i changed everyone to - read and write, then restarted apache, but nothing changed

Comment: no personal.com in the hosts file, just added to give a try:
`    127.0.0.1       localhost  
    127.0.0.1       personal.com  
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost  
   ::1             localhost  
    fe80::1%lo0     localhost  `

also tried your command to flush DNS cache, and restarted apache
but didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Weird, looks like restarting Apache and cache commands sometimes are not enough.
The message changed to 403-forbidden after a system restart.

I checked the ports with
`lsof -nP -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN` 
`lsof -nP -i4TCP:8050 | grep LISTEN` 
`lsof -nP -i4TCP:9050 | grep LISTEN`

and it showed 4 httpd process listening to :80 even with apache stopped, then after a reboot appeared a process listening in the correct port.